An error in your SQL syntax (Sql Query ), what is my Mistake
Please tell me what is my mistake in below code.
SELECT order_item.order_id, order_item.product_id, order_item.quantity, order_item.Rquantity, order_item.rate,
        order_item.total, product.product_name, orders.order_date, orders.client_name, customer.customer_name, customer.customer_mobile,
         order_item.quantity - order_item.Rquantity AS Turn, SUM(order_item.quantity) AS ST GROUP BY order_item.product_id  FROM  order_item 
        INNER JOIN product ON product.product_id = order_item.product_id 
        INNER JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = order_item.order_id
        INNER JOIN customer ON orders.client_name = customer.customer_id  
        WHERE orders.order_date BETWEEN '2020-05-02' AND '2024-05-28';

i an using above code but result show
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM  order_item

Group by comes after the where clause, not before from. Btw, you are using mariadb, not mysql. No, the two of them are not the same.

You will also have a problem with the columns of the group by clause after fixing this syntax error. Your products will have multiple orders, so what do you expect mysql to show for example for order date when you group by by product id only?

Please review https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/
